# Changing values in column based on another column in arcpy

Tags: arcpy, code-review

I created new field in a table named 'Cimp'. Now I want to put there values that depends on values from column "COS_Cod" for example, if COS_Cod starts with 1.1 then Cimp is equal to 1. COS_Cod is a text, Cimp must be a number, because I will use it later for calculations.

I write code that base on code that I found in "Refining an Automated Model for Basic Landform Classification A Python and ArcGIS Approach" by Josh Moss. I doesn't give me errors, but when I check table my Cimp is unchanged.

This is my code:

```
#adding the value
tableFile = "C:/Users/User/Desktop/project/COS_CAOP/results/ClippedCOS.dbf"
arcpy.AddField_management(tableFile, "Cimp", "FLOAT","","","","","NULLABLE")
print ("TABLE DONE")


#Let's try this method!

COS_Cod = "COS_Cod"
Cimp = "Cimp"

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(pClippedCOS, (COS_Cod, Cimp)) as updateRows:
    for lForms in updateRows:
        cosCodes = lForms[0]
        print cosCodes

        print "printed cosCodes"

        def codeCimpAssign(COS_Cod):
            if cosCodes == "1.1*":
                numCimp = 1.0
            elif cosCodes == "1.2*":
                numCimp = 1.0
            elif cosCodes == "1.3*":
                numCimp = 0.8
            elif cosCodes == "1.4*":
                numCimp = 0.4
            elif cosCodes == "2.1*" and cosCodes == "2.2*":
                numCimp = 0.35
            elif cosCodes == "2.4*":
                numCimp = 0.35
            elif cosCodes == "3.1*":
                numCimp = 0.0
            elif cosCodes == "3.2*":
                numCimp = 0.25
            elif cosCodes == "3.3*":
                numCimp = 0.8
            else:
                numCimp = 0.0
                print "something"
            return numCimp


# define "text" as relationship for updating rows
        numCimpValue = codeCimpAssign(cosCodes)
        print numCimpValue
        print "printed Cimp values"

#update rows

        lForms[1] = numCimpValue
        updateRows.updateRow(lForms)
        print "Added CImp values"
        arcpy.AddMessage("Added CImp values")
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues in your code. For example you cant use asterix to match beginnings of strings, instead use .startswith. You name input variable to function (COS_Cod) differently in the if statements (cosCodes), they need to be the same.

```
import arcpy

tableFile = "C:/Users/User/Desktop/project/COS_CAOP/results/ClippedCOS.dbf"

COS_Cod = "COS_Cod"
Cimp = "Cimp" #This is the field to update?


def codeCimpAssign(value):
    if value.startswith("1.1"):
        numCimp = 1.0
    elif value.startswith("1.2"):
        numCimp = 1.0
    #More elifs here...
    else:
        numCimp = 0.0
    return numCimp

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(tableFile,[COS_Cod, Cimp]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[1]=codeCimpAssign(row[0])
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

I manage to do it simply by changing cosCodes == "1.1*" so now this part looks like that:

```
    def codeCimpAssign(COS_Cod):
        if cosCodes[0:3] == "1.1":
            numCimp = 1.0
        elif cosCodes[0:3] == "1.2":
            numCimp = 1.0
            #rest of the code...
```

it worked and changed values in Cimp field correctly.